# Cannot modify specific variable values over a specific dimension in netcdf

Tags: netcdf, netcdf4, nco

I have a netcdf file containing 4-D variables:

```
variables:
    double maxvegetfrac(time_counter, veget, lat, lon) ;
        maxvegetfrac:_FillValue = 1.00000002004088e+20 ;
        maxvegetfrac:history = "From Topo.115MaCTRL_WAM_360_180" ;
        maxvegetfrac:long_name = "Vegetation types" ;
        maxvegetfrac:missing_value = 1.e+20f ;
        maxvegetfrac:name = "maxvegetfrac" ;
        maxvegetfrac:units = "-" ;

    double mask_veget(time_counter, veget, lat, lon) ;
        mask_veget:missing_value = -1.e+34 ;
        mask_veget:_FillValue = -1.e+34 ;
        mask_veget:long_name = "IF MYVEG4 EQ 10 AND I GE 610 AND J GT 286 THEN 16 ELSE MYVEG4" ;
        mask_veget:history = "From desert_115Ma_3" ;
```

I'd like to use the variable "mask_veget" as a mask to alter values of the variable "maxvegetfrac" over specific regions, and over chosen values of its "veget" dimension.
To do so I am using ncap2. For example, if I want to set maxvegetfrac values over the 5th rank of veget dimension to 500 where mask_veget equals 6, I do :

```
> ncap2 -s "where (mask_veget(:,:,:,:)== 6) maxvegetfrac(:,5,:,:) = 500" test.nc
```

My problem is that in the resulting test.nc file, maxvegetfrac has been modified at the first rank of "veget" dimension, not the 5th one. And I get the same result if I run the script over the entire veget dimension:

```
ncap2 -s "where (mask_veget(:,:,:,:)== 6) maxvegetfrac(:,:,:,:) = 500" test.nc
```

So I am mistaking somewhere, but... where ?
Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things you may not be aware of 
you shouldn't be hyperslabbing a variable in the where body  -it makes no sense at the moment.

It is ok to hyperslab in the where statement proving its a single index
as a dim with a single value collapses

Try this:

```
/*** hyper.nco *****/ 
maxvegetfrac5=maxvegetfrac(:,5,:,:);

where( mask_veget(:,5,:,:)== 6 )
   maxvegetfrac5=500.0;

/* put the hyperslab back in */
maxvegetfrac(:,5,:,:)=maxvegetfrac5;
/* script end *****/
```

run the script now with the command

```
ncap2 -v -O -S hyper.nco test.nc out.nc
```

...Henry